# How do I change the value by a variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I change the value of the needel down there. The code is for a speedometer and I  don't know how to get access to the value. I can't access variables Outside the method even if they are declared in the .h file. I just want to have the needle not to be controlled by the random function and the timer, I want them to reed the slider
I tried several things but even can't access the progress view. 
It would be great if you could help me.

The code is from here: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/ios-tutorial-custom-speedometer-control/

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize needleImageView;
@synthesize speedometerCurrentValue;
@synthesize prevAngleFactor;
@synthesize angle;
@synthesize speedometer_Timer;
@synthesize speedometerReading;
@synthesize maxVal;

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Add Meter Contents //
    [self addMeterViewContents];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [maxVal release];
    [needleImageView release];
    [speedometer_Timer release];
    [speedometerReading release];

    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public Methods

-(void) addMeterViewContents
{

    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,460)];
    backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bg.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
    [backgroundImageView release];


    /*UIImageView *meterImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 286,315)];
    meterImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meter.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:meterImageView];
    [meterImageView release];*/


    //  Needle //
    UIImageView *imgNeedle = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143,155, 22, 84)];
    self.needleImageView = imgNeedle;
    [imgNeedle release];

    self.needleImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(self.needleImageView.layer.anchorPoint.x, self.needleImageView.layer.anchorPoint.y*2);
    self.needleImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.needleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.needleImageView];

    // Needle Dot //
    UIImageView *meterImageViewDot = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(131.5, 175, 45,44)];
    meterImageViewDot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"center_wheel.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:meterImageViewDot];
    [meterImageViewDot release];

    // Speedometer Reading //
    UILabel *tempReading = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 250, 60, 30)];
    self.speedometerReading = tempReading;
    [tempReading release];
    self.speedometerReading.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    self.speedometerReading.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.speedometerReading.text= @"0";
    self.speedometerReading.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:114/255.f green:146/255.f blue:38/255.f alpha:1.0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.speedometerReading ];

    // Set Max Value //
    self.maxVal = @"100";

    /// Set Needle pointer initialy at zero //
    [self rotateIt:-118.4];

    // Set previous angle //
    self.prevAngleFactor = -118.4;

    // Set Speedometer Value //
    [self setSpeedometerCurrentValue];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark calculateDeviationAngle Method

-(void) calculateDeviationAngle
{

    if([self.maxVal floatValue]>0)
    {
        self.angle = ((self.speedometerCurrentValue *237.4)/[self.maxVal floatValue])-118.4;  // 237.4 - Total angle between 0 - 100 //
    }
    else
    {
        self.angle = 0;
    }

    if(self.angle<=-118.4)
    {
        self.angle = -118.4;  
    }
    if(self.angle>=119)
    {
        self.angle = 119;
    }


    // If Calculated angle is greater than 180 deg, to avoid the needle to rotate in reverse direction first rotate the needle 1/3 of the calculated angle and then 2/3. // 
    if(abs(self.angle-self.prevAngleFactor) >180)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
        [self rotateIt:self.angle/3];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
        [self rotateIt:(self.angle*2)/3];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

    self.prevAngleFactor = self.angle;


    // Rotate Needle //
    [self rotateNeedle];


}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark rotateNeedle Method
-(void) rotateNeedle
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f]; 
    [self.needleImageView setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI / 180) * self.angle)];  
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark setSpeedometerCurrentValue

-(void) setSpeedometerCurrentValue
{
    if(self.speedometer_Timer)
    {
        [self.speedometer_Timer invalidate];
        self.speedometer_Timer = nil;
    }
    float hilfe = arc4random() % 100;
    self.speedometerCurrentValue =  hilfe; // Generate Random value between 0 to 100. //
    progress.progress = hilfe/100;
    self.speedometer_Timer = [NSTimer  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(setSpeedometerCurrentValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    self.speedometerReading.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",self.speedometerCurrentValue];

    // Calculate the Angle by which the needle should rotate //
    [self calculateDeviationAngle];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Speedometer needle Rotation View Methods

-(void) rotateIt:(float)angl
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.01f];

    [self.needleImageView setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI / 180) *angl)]; 

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Slider changed

-(IBAction) silderchanged:(id)sender
{
    int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
    sliderbox.text = newText;
    //progress.progress = ((slider.value + 0.5f)/100);
}


@end
```

Comment: You should set propper tags on your question to get ans answer. And please mention what language that is.

Comment: It's Objective-C and for the iPhone. This is my first question here, and I don't really know how to handle with everything in here. I would ask for your indulgence.

Comment: Sure, we all start. First: change the tag 'value' you chose for this question to: 'iphone' 'objective-c'

Answer (score 0):

A general idea:

1. Create a slider (you can directly place the control on the xib file in IB)
2. Add an IBOutlet in the controller's header file
3. link them up in IB
4. Add and implement an IBAction in the controller
5. link the slider to this action
6. the IBAction function will set self.speedometerCurrentValue to the slider value
7. remove the timer

This is how I implemented the IBAction I mentioned in point 6

```
-(IBAction) setValue:(id)sender {
    float  f = [sliderValue value];
    NSLog(@"get this %f", f);

    // should be refactored
    self.speedometerCurrentValue = f;
    self.speedometerReading.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",self.speedometerCurrentValue];

    [self calculateDeviationAngle];
}
```

[image: slider and the meter]

Comment: I added as you described above a slider and for me also a label in the .m file I also added -(IBAction) silderchanged:(id)sender
{
 int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
 NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
 sliderbox.text = newText;
 //progress.progress = ((slider.value + 0.5f)/100);
 //self.maxVal = 100;
 self.speedometerCurrentValue =[slider value];
 [self setSpeedometerCurrentValue];
}
I also commented the lines concerning the timer as well as arc4random
I still dosen't work. But slider and my new label work. What the hell am i doing wrong

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.3.3. Sample code here:  https://github.com/reader20/OpenRepository/tree/master/Stackoverflow/SpeedometerDemo